# mmenu taking full page instead of sliding

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, mmenu

I'm working on a Cordova/PhoneGap project where I use jQuery/ jQuery Mobile and an excellent plugin called mmenu from http://mmenu.frebsite.nl.

I am doing an .ajax call from a remote server and creating the  menu content and appending it to the jQM header section, which is fine.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://localhost/service/action',
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    contentType: "application/javascript",
    jsonp: 'callback',
    jsonpCallback: 'mycallback',
    async: false,
    error: function() {
        alert("Error");
    },
    success: function(data) {
        var html = "";

        $.each(data, function(index, element) {
           html += '<li><a href="' + element + '.html">' + element + '</a></li>';
        });

        html = '<nav id="menu"><ul>' + html + '<ul></nav>';

        $("body").append(html);
    }
});
```

The HTML page header section where the menu is shown:

```
<div data-role="header">
     <a href="#menu" data-icon="grid" data-iconpos="notext">Menu</a>
     <h1>Demo</h1>
</div>
```

All things appears fine..

**My Question:**

But when I click on the menu, the menu does not slide.. but it takes the whole page with a white background. All the expected menu content are there.. but not as a sliding panel..

Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Can you set up a demo of this in jsfiddle or plunker?

Comment: I tried doing that as I usually do that for all my questions. But for this I felt some difficult in replicating the issue in a fiddle. My exact scenario uses ajax call from localhost and cordova js files.. If  you could point me to existing fiddle related to mmenu, I can modify that.

Comment: It might not be compatible with JQM. Try `$.mobile.activePage.append(html);`.

Comment: actually the content is appended before the <body> tag, so its fine. The mmenu plugin expect the <nav> id to be anywhere inside body.

Comment: why don't you just use the [JQM panel](http://view.jquerymobile.com/master/demos/panel/)? From what I see your plugin just does the same as JQM's.

Comment: This plugin has more features in-built which is ready to use.. so I want to use this one.. which is really good.

Comment: Should you not fire the plugin after inserting the HTML in to the DOM?

Comment: I have done as shown in some examples that came along with the plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @frequent, I have moved to JQM Panels as I am not able to solve this problem with mmenu for past few days.

jQM Swipe Panel design:

http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0/docs/examples/panels/panel-swipe-open.php#demo-page